# CVS: Check out branch at specific date

Tags: date, command-line, branch, command-line-interface, cvs

I want to check out a project at a specific date on a specific branch in CVS.

Do you know how I can do this via the command line?

Comment: Please specify what CVS you are using (git, svn, mercurial, ...)?

Comment: @Peter I'm using CVS: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System

Comment: My bad, confused the shortcut with VCS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To get all files for a particular date on the branch, check out the
>   branchpoint and then update with all changes between the branchpoint
>   and the desired date.  For example

```
BRANCH="gcc-3_2-branch"
DATE="2002-09-01"
cvs co -r ${BRANCH}point gcc
cvs up -d -j${BRANCH}point -j${BRANCH}:"${DATE}"
```

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2002-12/msg01341.html